# Ask my girlfriend to prom

Tags: puzzle-creation

This puzzle is a little different from most of the ones on this site.  Instead of solving a puzzle we will be making a puzzle with the most creative receiving the extra +20 rep as a bonus.

#### Puzzle

Prom is coming up shortly and time is running out!  I am too shy to just walk up and ask her out so have decided that I shall make a half sheet of paper with a puzzle of any kind on it.  Now it is up to you to design the puzzle and its solution so that I'm not lonely at Prom!

#### Rules

- Must fit on one sheet of paper
- Preferably includes something music related
- Preferably something along the lines of "Will you go to prom with me?" somewhere in the puzzle but it can be slightly modified to flow well with your answer.
- Preferably includes a reference to "three years later"

Comment: define "most creative"